# Adding elements to a Beamer template

Tags: beamer

I would like to add the footline containing short author/title/page number (like in the Boadilla theme) to the Singapore theme (Basically I would like Singapore plus a footline).
I want this simply in a presentation (not creating a new template). I tried to look in the documentation and on the web but I cannot find an easy way to do it. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `Boadilla` theme uses the footline from the `infolines` outer theme. You can copy the definition to your presentation and change the colours as you like:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\author{names}
\title{text}

\usetheme{Singapore}



\makeatletter


\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor\expandafter\ifblank\expandafter{\beamer@shortinstitute}{}{~~(\insertshortinstitute)}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,leftskip=2ex,rightskip=2ex,sep=0pt]{date in head/foot}%
    \hfill%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}%
    \insertshortdate{}%
    \hfill%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{page number in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{page number in head/foot}%
    \usebeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother



\setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{use=structure,fg=black,bg=structure.fg!40!white}
\setbeamercolor{title in head/foot}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg!60!white}
\setbeamercolor{date in head/foot}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg!90!white}


\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{title}
    abc
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfectly! I just substituted the \insertshortdate with \insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber{}
as I wanted the  slide number rather than the date.

Comment: @BeamerUser Personally I would use `\date{}
\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[totalframenumber]` if you want to show the frame number